# You used BCP - Better Configurable Products for Magento 1.9.2.2 - 1.9.2.4?

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product

Has anyone here tried to use Magento extension BCP - Better Configurable Products with Magento 1.9.2.2 or later? (Don't remember if links are discouraged. Sorry, if so.) The site at http://www.nr-apps.com/store/bcp-better-configurable-products.html shows it to be compatible with 1.9, but not higher. Sometimes developers don't keep up with compatibility, and these guys don't answer questions since it's a free extension.

It looks like it might be a good substitution for Matt Dean's SCP - SimpleConfigurableProducts extension, which they also claim on this site, if it works beyond 1.9.

Since it is a free item, which they encourage further development, is there anyone willing to test it and/or tweak it, if necessary, to ensure it works with 1.9.2.2 through 1.9.2.4?

Comment: SCP is still maintained by a few forks nowadays including Aligent and Obigroup. As far as BCP is concerned I have no familiarity with the product. Apologies.

Comment: AFAIK, BCP is not actively maintained anymore, that's probably why the recent versions are not tested. It might work, it might not. And if not, you still can try to buy support from nr-apps to make it compatible.

Comment: BCP can be found in this repository: https://bitbucket.org/netresearch/dmp_betterconfigurableproducts I cannot comment, because of low reputation here, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I know scp working in 1.9 or higher version and work for me 1.9.1.1

This Extension working in 1.9 you need to change some line

Steps shown below url

```
http://teition.com/price-indexer-will-not-re-index-in-magento/
```

and also move file From `base/default` to your theme this things work for me in `1.9.1.1`

Please try and let me know